# Installing phalcon on apps Mac OS

Tags: php, macos, phalcon, ampps

I am really struggling with getting phalcon up and running in my ampps installation. I believe its correctly installed on my system because when I run php -m, I see the phalcon module. However, when I put

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

in a file (info.php) and in the www directory and load it in the browser, the phalcon module doesn't show up. I am relatively new to both php and ampps, so I know i'm definitely doing something wrong. Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, try to restart apache.

Second, make sure that you installed with this tutorial, using homebrew: https://docs.phalconphp.com/pt/latest/reference/install.html#mac-os-x

Comment: I restarted apache, and reinstalled phalcon, but I still wasn't able to get it to work. Ended up switching to a linux virtual machine and installing LAMP. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow the installation docs here https://phalconphp.com/en/download/linux (follow that which belongs to your distro)
2. Then add this line extension=phalcon.so  to your php.ini located in your Ampps folder. for me it was located at /usr/local/ampps/php-7.1/etc
3. Then copy the phalcon.so file located at /usr/lib/php/{number digits} and place in you Ampps extension directory  /usr/local/ampps/php-7.1/lib/extensions/ext
4. Then restart your Ampps and open the php extensions from the UI. Then enable the phalcon extension from the popup

[image]